# How to query and return all documents in documentdb using linq

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

```
let problemDocument = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ProblemDatabaseModel>("")

problemDocument
```

doesn't seem to work

```
(problemDocument.Select(fun problem -> problem))
```

doesn't seem to work

```
(problemDocument.Where(fun problem -> problem.id = problem.id))
```

doesn't seem to work either.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query all document in document db, please try to below code:

`documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ProblemDatabaseModel>("").ToList();`

Please note that, we can store different json entity in documentDB, if document property does not in your data model, it will give a default value. I have a simple test for this:

Data model:

```
public class Cred
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "credits")]
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "authordetails")]
    public AuthDetail AuthInfo { get; set; }
}
```

If json data in documentDB is:

```
{
  "id": "CDC103",
  "title": "Fundamentals of database design",

  "authordetails": {
    "Name": "dave",
    "Age": 33
  },
  "custom":"test"
}
```

`client.CreateDocumentQuery<Cred>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("jambordb", "jamborcols")).ToList();`

Here is the result:

[image]

From the screenshot we know that, the property "custom" will not included in our data model. and the credits will give a default value 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your answer is exactly what I asked for, but now I realize, I actually don't want all my documents.  Really what I want is all documents that are of type ProblemDatabaseModel.  Is there a clever way to go about this with linq without resorting to a string query?  Can linq support type checking functions such as IS_DEFINED?  I have implemented something similar for a different document type but it required me to add a property "nodeType": "tag".  Then I use a Where clause to filter out documents with that property.  Thanks!

Comment: As I know, It is not support at currently. Add a property is a workaround for this scenario.